# Heat pump running too much

Tags: thermostat, vent, gates

We built a house 3 years ago. It has two heat pumps and the upstairs one runs way more than it used to. The temp is set to 68 and every time we go upstairs to check it it says the temp is 68 but it’s still running. We do have an extra room over our garage that my husband keeps his guitars in and we keep the door shut to keep our pets out of there and the room is a good 10 degrees colder. The room also has an air intake vent as well. My question is, does the intake vent have anything to do with the thermostat and does the cold air going into the system trick the thermostat to thinking the whole upstairs is cold? I have suggested getting a baby gate to put up to keep the pets out of the room but allow us to keep the door open to heat the room and keep it all a consistent temperature but my husband says it has nothing to do with it and something is wrong with the system. Just asking here before we have someone out to look at it and we spend a ton of money that a $50 gate could solve. Thank you!!

Comment: It could just be that it's cold outside and the heat pump is doing its job. If the thermostat is set to 68 and the temp is 68 then I'd expect it to shut off, or at least slow down. That said, most(?) heat pumps have weather compensation so it may continue running if it anticipates that the weather is going to be chilly or that it's more efficient to overrun slightly.

Comment: I would have thought that too but this has been going on for a while now and was doing it when it was still in the 50’s outside. It’s definitely more noticeable this year than the two prior years.

Comment: Most thermostats will over shoot the temperature by a degree or two before shutoff, so a 68 set point, they will turn off at 70.  They will then cool down to 66 before turning on again.  I am just guessing heat pumps work the same way.

Comment: Do you have AUX heating on the upstairs pump?

Comment: Could be something laughably simple, like the fan being set to run all the time, rather than only for heat/cool - would depend on the unit and the settings. Are you seeing a lot more power use, or just finding the fan running?

Comment: We are definitely seeing more power use. Our electric bill has been almost double what it has been the last couple of years with the same temperatures outside.